# Can you get Method name that threw Exception?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, stack-trace

Is there a C# method that returns to the upper-most caller, the Name of **MY Method** that threw an exception, even if the **actual exception** was thrown by another (e.g. database driver errors when my method calls it) ?

*Caller -> MyMethod -> DbDriver(error)*

*I want "MyMethod", not "DbDriver"*

I'd rather not re-throw exceptions all the way up the chain.

My current kludge, is to iterate through the StackTrace frames, and parse out my Method using `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType`.

Is there a built-in method to get this information or a more elegant solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the information you require not just in the stack trace itself?

Comment: @Arran -- is is in the stack trace, it just feels kind of kludgey to me to get it this way.

Comment: I resolved by checking this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27997276/get-method-name-that-threw-exception

Answer (score 16):

Use [`Exception.TargetSite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.targetsite%28VS.90%29.aspx) property to get the method name

> Gets the method that throws the current exception.

Comment: I looked at `Exception.TargetSite`, but the problem is the property can return method names that are not **mine**.

For example: if an ODBC error is thrown in my method, TargetSite will return the ODBC method name, rather than **my method name** that the error occured in.

(I will edit my OP to make this a bit clearer)

Comment: @EuroMarkus, in that case your current approach for going through stack-trace frames is probably the way to go. I don't think there is a direct way available in .Net framework.

Comment: ex.TargetSite.Name

Answer (score 0):

You need the stack trace ability.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.environment.stacktrace(v=vs.80).aspx