# Get Method name that threw exception

Tags: c#, exception

I know. A similar question has already asked.

- [How to get the name of the method that caused the exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598255/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-method-that-caused-the-exception)

but I haven't got the exact solution from that.

I have a button click event in which I have a method `FillCombo()`.

**Button Click event**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      try
      {
          cmbTemplates.Items.Clear();
          lstFiles.Clear();
          FillCombo();                
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
           MethodBase site = ex.TargetSite;
           Log(ex.ToString(), site == null ? null : site.Name);                
      }
}
```

When I debugged, I found that the exception occurs from `FillCombo()` method. After that I get the value of `site.Name` as `WinIOError` instead of `FillCombo`.

I tried another method `GetExecutingMethodName()` which was answered by **Chris Gessler** in [How to get the name of the method that caused the exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598255/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-method-that-caused-the-exception) question. So I tried sending the name of method that caused exception using `GetExecutingMethodName()` method

```
Log(ex.ToString(), GetExecutingMethodName());
```

But I got the result as `System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick` instead of `FillCombo`.

**How do I get the actual name of method that caused exception?**

Comment: use breakpoints to debug your code and look at stacktrace

Comment: I can know in Dubug mode. But I need to log the errors to a file. In production environment who is going to sit and Debug!!! @saurabh64

Comment: You should log the entire stack trace.  This will usually give enough context to determine the issue.

Comment: `I get the value of site.Name as WinIOError instead of FillCombo`. That's likely, because your `FillCombo` does not throw exception, but deeper into that when we call into the framework code which throws the exception.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

.net supports getting the stack trace information from an exception. You could filter out the method (and its name) by examining the first frame (origin).

```
new StackTrace(ex).GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name
```

This would probably give you exactly the same as the targetsite (the win io), but you can examine the stacktrace for the first user code, or the first frame in your type, or whichever your needs.

For example, getting the name of the culprit thrower in your current assembly:

```
var s = new StackTrace(ex);
var thisasm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();                
var methodname = s.GetFrames().Select(f => f.GetMethod()).First(m => m.Module.Assembly == thisasm).Name;
```

Comment: How is this different from the `Exception.TargetSite` property? And how would that get the OP's `FillCombo()` method name?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Please see edit. The stacktrace out of the exception was the entry point for filtering out the exact needs. Was a bit slow in adding the example due to lack of visual studio at my current location, and was searching for dotnetfiddle ;)

Comment: Perfectly working. I tried the code. I could even get the name of event in case an exception is occured before executing FillCombo method. Thanks a lot :) @Me.Name

Comment: @SarathAvanavu: respectfully, it's not clear this is the solution you are looking for. This technique will return the first method from the currently executing assembly found in the stack trace, which may or may not be the method from the current method body that was called when the exception happened. I.e. if `FillCombo()` had called another method `Foo()` in the current assembly, which _then_ called into some other library which eventually threw the exception, the above would return the name "Foo" and not "FillCombo". If that's what you want, very good...otherwise see my answer.

Answer (score 11):

It is important to understand what is meant by "the method that threw the exception". When an exception occurs, there is a specific method that is actually executing. Just because at some point before the exception, you called your own `FillCombo()` method, that doesn't mean that's the method that threw the exception.

The `FillCombo()` method will however (in the case you care about here) be in the stack trace. That's why it's useful to log the entire stack trace. Indeed, I just generally log the whole `Exception` object (i.e. `ex.ToString()`, or just pass the exception object to `string.Format()` or similar which will call `ToString()` for you). This will include the exception type, the message, the entire stack trace, and even inner exception information if present.

The code you got from the other question, for the `GetExecutingMethodName()` method, is not really all that useful IMHO. You'll note that what it really does is crawl through the stack trace of the *current* executing location, looking for the first method that is declared in a type other than the one where the `GetExecutingMethodName()` was declared.

This is wrong for your purpose for two reasons:

1. It appears you've declared that method in the same class where your `Click` event handler is declared. This means the event handler method is ignored, and so you get the caller of that method, which is the `Control.OnClick()` method (i.e. the method that actually raises the event).

Frankly, I find that particular answer odd, because .NET already provides an API for retrieving the `MethodInfo` of the currently executing method: [MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod(v=vs.110).aspx). And this is way more reliable than the code Chris Gessler wrote.

2. More problematic, you don't have an opportunity to call this method at the point where the exception is thrown! At best (i.e. even if you deal with the question of where the helper method is declared), all that calling that will tell you is that you are in your `button1_Click()` method. But you already know that, because the code you're writing to handle the exception is in that method.

If you want to know the name of the method in your currently executing method that was called before the exception occurred, you can combine the two techniques: get the name of the currently executing method, and then pass that to a method that takes both that and the stack trace string from the `Exception` object, and let that method parse the stack trace string to find the frame just before the currently executing method in the trace.

It's a bit of a pain, but it could be done. Here's an example of what that would look like (simple proof-of-concept console program):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        CallForException();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred calling {0} method", GetCallForExceptionThisMethod(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), e));
    }
}

private static string GetCallForExceptionThisMethod(MethodBase methodBase, Exception e)
{
    StackTrace trace = new StackTrace(e);
    StackFrame previousFrame = null;

    foreach (StackFrame frame in trace.GetFrames())
    {
        if (frame.GetMethod() == methodBase)
        {
            break;
        }

        previousFrame = frame;
    }

    return previousFrame != null ? previousFrame.GetMethod().Name : null;
}

private static void CallForException()
{
    DoActualException();
}

private static void DoActualException()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Finally, keep in mind that due to method inlining and other optimizations, even a full stack trace may have some irregularities in it, including not even having the actual name of the method where the exception was thrown. That's another reason that logging the entire `Exception` object is usually much more useful; the more context, the more likely you are to be able to reconstruct what happened.

Answer (score 6):

Just try this:

```
var methodFullName = exception.TargetSite.ReflectedType.FullName
```